# Material UI Icons not visible on hosting my MERN stack project on Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, material-ui, mern

I am working on a MERN stack project for which I have created a side bar and have used Material UI for the icons. The sidebar works perfectly fine locally, but when I open the heroku link for the same, the icons are not visible. (see images below for better understanding)

**Note: I have used the icons on the Dashboard which will be visible only after you log in**

Image when running Locally:
[Locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyx6c.png)

Image when hosted on Heroku:
[On Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJGuK.png)

Code of my Sidebar:

```
import React, {useContext} from "react"
import "./Sidebar.css"
import { NavLink, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import HomeIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Home';
import EqualizerIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Equalizer';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import PersonIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Person';
import { Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react'

import { UserContext } from '../pages/AuthContext';


class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isSidebarOpen: false,
      username: props.username,
      userId: props.userId,
      sidebarClass: "sidenav",
    };
    this.onClickSidebarOpen = this.onClickSidebarOpen.bind(this)
  }
  onClickSidebarOpen(){
    this.setState(prevState => {
      if(!prevState.isSidebarOpen)
        {
          return {
            isSidebarOpen: true,
            sidebarClass: "sidenavOpen",
          }
        }
        else if(prevState.isSidebarOpen)
          {
            return {
              isSidebarOpen: false,
              sidebarClass: "sidenav",
            }
          }
    })
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className={this.state.sidebarClass} >
        <ul>
          <span onClick={this.onClickSidebarOpen} className="hamburger">
            <li className="hamburger"><a>
              <span className="icons">
                <MenuIcon />
              </span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </span>

          <span>
            <li className="sidenav-item">
              <NavLink to="/dashboard">
                <span className="icons">
                  <HomeIcon />
                </span>
                <span className="options">SkillBoard</span>
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="sidenav-item">
              <Link to = "/overall-analytics">
                <span className="icons">
                  <EqualizerIcon /> 
                </span>
                <span className="options">Analytics</span>
              </Link>
            </li>

            <li className="sidenav-item">
              <NavLink to="/Review-more">
                <span className="icons">
                  <SearchIcon />
                </span>
                <span className="options">ReviewMore</span>
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="sidenav-item">
              <NavLink to={`/profile/${this.state.username}`}>
                <span className="icons">
                  <PersonIcon />
                </span>
                <span className="options">Profile</span>
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="sidenav-item">
              <NavLink to = {`/portfolio/${this.state.userId}`} target ="_blank" >
                <span className="icons">
                  <Icon name='address book' />
                </span>
                <span className="options">Portfolio</span>
              </NavLink>
            </li>
          </span>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function SidebarFunc() {
  const [user, setUser] = useContext(UserContext);
  return (
    <Sidebar username = {user.username} userId = {user.id} />
  );

}


export default SidebarFunc;
```

My Package.json for the frontend:

```
{


"name": "skillly",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.10.18",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment": "^28.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles": "^28.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote": "^28.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-balloon": "^28.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckfinder": "^28.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials": "^28.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^3.0.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.58",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "apexcharts": "^3.25.0",
    "autosize": "^4.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "flesch": "^1.0.5",
    "flesch-kincaid": "github:daveross/flesch-kincaid",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "gasp": "0.0.2",
    "gsap": "^3.6.0",
    "html-react-parser": "^1.2.6",
    "loadash": "^1.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.7",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-gsap": "^2.2.1",
    "react-hook-reading-time": "^1.0.0",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^8.3.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.3",
    "syllables": "^1.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
}
```

My Application logs on Heroku:

```
2021-08-09T14:59:26.562853+00:00 app[web.1]: hello
2021-08-09T14:59:26.567157+00:00 app[web.1]: hello
2021-08-09T14:59:26.567425+00:00 app[web.1]: hello
2021-08-09T14:59:26.567864+00:00 app[web.1]: hello
2021-08-09T14:59:26.568073+00:00 app[web.1]: hello
2021-08-09T14:59:26.568463+00:00 app[web.1]: hello
2021-08-09T14:59:26.568890+00:00 app[web.1]: hello
2021-08-09T14:59:26.569304+00:00 app[web.1]: hello
2021-08-09T14:59:26.570934+00:00 app[web.1]: hello
2021-08-09T14:59:26.600456+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/overallAnalytics/60ba74fe58bb8d6268e11971" host=skillly1.herokuapp.com request_id=d0f82226-eecf-4bdd-b408-66ae6cff8d81 fwd="117.97.166.236" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1664ms status=304 bytes=184 protocol=https
```

My project repository (which is hosted on heroku)
[Github Repo](https://github.com/SKILLLY/Main-Website)

My heroku website link: [Link to website](https://skillly1.herokuapp.com/)

I am new to MERN stack and Heroku which is why I am having a hard time figuring out what exactly am I doing wrong. Please Help!!

I am not really sure what exactly is causing such an error, so in case you want me to add anything else to the question, do let me know.

Comment: Check your DOM on the hosted page, does your icons exist in DOM structure? Also some errors in page code inspector? Plus, console.log sideBarClass inside onClickSidebarOpen to check if it's a problem with variables.

Comment: @IlliaChil Yes, I did check the DOM. The icons are there. Their HTML is showing up and they are taking up some height and width. Yet for some reason they are not visible

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had used `opacity: 75%` in the CSS of these icons which for some reason was making the opacity of these icons as 1% on the DOM. I removed it completely from the CSS and it works perfectly fine now.